# How to do a order by when doing a right join

Tags: sql, join, sql-order-by

I have the following two queries:

```
    $query2 = "SELECT DID,title,description,doc_type,time_added,date_added,
    downloadcount from docs where public='1' AND active='1' order by downloadcount 
    $sort limit $pagingstart, $config[items_per_page]";

    $query3 = "select members.ptitle, members.firstname, members.lastname from 
    members right join docs on members.userid=docs.userid";
```

I have successfully done a RIGHT JOIN to match the USERID on the two tables.

I however cannot get the order by downloadcount to order properly. The current output as follows:

Please note, for this output

- Dr Tylor is USERID 25
- Mr Raymond is USERID 1

A username is split into 3 - Title, First Name, Last Name

```
   USERNAME               | DOC NAME  |DOWNLOAD COUNT
--------------------------------------------------------    
    Dr. Fred Tyler        | DOC-A     | 3
    Mr. Raymond Franco    | DOC-B     | 1
    Dr. King Raymond      | DOC-C     | 0
    Mr. Raymond Franco    | DOC-Z     | 0
```

Now, the problem I am faced with is that DOC-A actually belongs to  My Raymond Franco and DOC-B belongs to Dr Fred Tyler.

Is there any way I can join the two tables and sort by download count without the output being jumbled?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you build you schema at http://sqlfiddle.com ? it will be more clear for us.

Comment: I don't understand at all, what the problem is. How do you determine which docs belong together? What does this all have to do with your second query? The right join in it doesn't really make sense, btw. You're not selecting anything from docs table. You seem to want to join the members table in your first query, though.

Comment: Hi Fancypants

Basically what I am trying to achieve is the following:

Match USERNAME to DOC (done - by using right join to join the USERID's in docs table and members table).

Sort by download count..

Please note, I have only been php/sql programming for 6 months and all is self taught, so if you have a better or more effecient way for joining data in two tables and sorting by download count - that would be great.

Comment: Can you post the create table, inserts and the output you want to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do it all in a single SELECT?

```
$query2 = "SELECT 
  members.ptitle, 
  members.firstname,      
  members.lastname,
  docs.DID,
  docs.title,
  docs.description,
  docs.doc_type,
  docs.time_added,
  docs.date_added,
  docs.downloadcount 
FROM members
INNER JOIN docs ON members.userid=docs.userid";
WHERE public='1' 
AND active='1' 
ORDER BY downloadcount 
$sort limit $pagingstart, $config[items_per_page]";
```

Comment: Hey @StevieG - AWESOME!! that bit of code is exactly what was required. Works 100%.

Thanks - will be coming to you with more issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try with this:

```
$query2 = "SELECT d.DID, d.title, d.description, d.doc_type, d.time_added, d.date_added, d.downloadcount,
members.ptitle, members.firstname, members.lastname 
from docs d
left join members on members.userid = d.userid
where d.public='1' AND d.active='1' 
order by d.downloadcount 
$sort limit $pagingstart, $config[items_per_page]";
```

I guess [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) would be a good read for you.